# Error for trapezoidal method increases with N if integral equals 0

Tags: python, calculus

I've written a simple implementation of the trapezoidal method to find the integral of sine:

```
def trapezoidal_method(a: float, b: float, n: int) -> float:
    length = (b - a)/n
    integral = 0
    start = a
    integral += math.sin(a)/2
    for _ in range(1, n):
        integral += math.sin(start + length)
        start += length
    integral += math.sin(b)/2
    return integral * length
```

It converges as expected for most situations...
[image: Proper behavior]
but it goes crazy when the result should be 0 (like integrating from -1 to 1):
[image: Bad behavior]

How do I fix this? Tried explicitly casting n to float and tried using the *decimal* library, didn't change anything

Comment: but if you look at the scale factor of the y-axis of the 2nd plot is almost 0 (order of e-15)

Comment: Yes, but I'm curious why this is happening

Comment: Because of numerical instability. It is simply not possible to expect floating-point types to work well in this sort of environment, because of what they fundamentally **are**. if the linked duplicate doesn't adequately answer the question for you, it would be better rephrased as a question for [math.se].

Comment: Probably the error increases with N because it is accumulated with the iterations. More about Python's [floating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/455634/16462878) numbers

Answer (score 0):

That's (mainly) due to floating number precision. In the case of functions as *sine*, which are transcendental by nature, only an approximation of it is possible (or depends on its implementation).

By adding a (very quick!) a print of the x and y values at each term of the sequence you will see the *odd symmetry* is not respected... or at least with a small error. So, *f(x) = -f(-x) + error*.

```
import math


def trapezoidal_method(func, a: float, b: float, n: int) -> float:
    length = (b - a)/n
    integral = 0
    start = a
    integral += func(a)/2
    for _ in range(1, n):
        integral += func(start + length)
        start += length
    integral += func(b)/2

    # evaluation for each term of the sequence
    print(0, f'x={a}  y={func(a)}') 
    x = a
    for i in range(1, n):
        x += length
        y = func(x)
        print(i, f'{x=}  {y=}')     

    print(n, f'x={b}  y={func(b)}')
    return integral * length
```

A test with `sin`

```
a, b, n = -1, 1, 7
func = math.sin
tm = trapezoidal_method(func, a, b, n)
```

Output

```
0 x=-1                  y=-0.8414709848078965
1 x=-0.7142857142857143 y=-0.6550778971785186
2 x=-0.4285714285714286 y=-0.41557185499305205 # <-
3 x=-0.1428571428571429 y=-0.1423717297922637
4 x= 0.1428571428571428 y=0.1423717297922636
5 x= 0.4285714285714285 y=0.41557185499305194  # <-
6 x= 0.7142857142857142 y=0.6550778971785185
8 x= 1                   y=0.8414709848078965
-1.586032892321652e-16
```

Notice that also the x-values maybe slightly different!

By choosing suitable limits of integration **and** amount of strips then the in some cases the integral maybe 0. Here an example with the diagonal function

```
a, b, n = -1, 1, 6
func = lambda x: x
tm = trapezoidal_method(func, a, b, n)
```

Output

```
0 x=-3.0 y=-3.0
1 x=-2.0 y=-2.0
2 x=-1.0 y=-1.0
3 x=0.0 y=0.0
4 x=1.0 y=1.0
5 x=2.0 y=2.0
7 x=3.0 y=3.0
0.0
```